# Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest

Tags: html, application-cache

In my browser app, I use an HTML5 ApplicationCache manifest which is valid according to http://manifest-validator.com/validate

It looks as follows

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# MYAPPNAME 5.8.33

CACHE:
index.html
app.js

NETWORK:
*
```

When I load the app, Google Chrome (Version 46.0.2490.86 m for Windows) throws the following error:

> Application Cache Error event: Failed to parse manifest http://192.168.0.3/development.nsf/WebApp/cache.appcache     index.html:1

Why is that and how can I get it to work?